# How can a shader read a vertex information?

Tags: directx, shader, pipeline, vertex

I have lately learned a shader.
Speeking of this as I know simply,
First, Make a buffer that saves vertices information.
Then make a shader file and compile.
Finally, Set a shader and Draw.
But studying code, I guess that there is no direct connection between 
a shader and buffer has vertices. So I wonder **How can a shader read a vertex information?** Just does a shader read a existent buffer?
I am not sure that my intend will be well delivered.
Because I can't speak English well. I hope you guys understand me.

Comment: It depends on pipeline and the version of Direct3D you are referring to

Comment: Basically, you supply vertex data (position, texture coordinate, color, tangent etc) and bind those data to vertex shader. How you do it will depend on the version of Direct3D you are referring to

Comment: in d3d11 before calling your shader you call IASetVertexBuffers(positionOfmyBuffer, nbBuffer, &m_vertexBuffer, &stride, &offset); https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476456%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You are not mentioned about the InputLayout, to render it is necessary to define in the context:
Vertex buffer,
Index buffer (optional),
Input layout (how the data will be distributed in the Vertex Shader parameters, sizes, types, "offset for each stride"),
VS and PS